# Wrong search generated with Python requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

What I'm trying to do is search StackOverflow for answers. I know it's probably been done before, but I'd like to do it again. With a GUI. Anyway that is a little bit down the road as right now i'm just trying to get to the page with the most votes for a question. I noticed while trying to see how to get into a nested div to get the link for the first answer that my search was off and taking me to the wrong place. I am using BeautifulSoup and Requests and python3 to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload = {'q': 'open GL cube'}
page = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/search",params=payload)
print(" URL IS ", page.url)
data = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
top = soup.find('a', {'title':'Highest voted search results'})['href']

print(top)
page2 = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com",params=top)
print(page2.url)
data2 = page2.content
topSoup = BeautifulSoup(data2, 'lxml')
for div in topSoup.find_all('div', {'class':'result-link'}):
    print(div.text)
```

i get the link and it outputs /search?tab=votes&q=open%GL%20cube

but when I pass it in with the params it does 
https://stackoverflow.com/?/search?tab=votes&q=open%GL%20cube

I would like to get rid of the /?/

Comment: can't you just replace it by nothing? (ok this is ugly :))

Comment: it has something to do with the encoding i think... it just randomly attaches it there for some reason.

Comment: Why not just do: `"https://stackoverflow.com" + top`? `top`'s value is not a valid input type for `params`, hence you won't get what you're expecting there unless you parse it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass it as parameters, just add it to the URL:

```
page2 = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com" + top)
```

Once you pass `requests` parameters it adds a `?` to the link before concatenating the new parameters to the link.

[Requests - Passing Parameters In URLs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Also, as stated, you should really use the API.

Comment: Yes this is what i ended up doing. I will probably redo this with the API once i have it figured it out, I'm pretty bad at reading APIs but i really need to get better. So i will have to figure that out, and spend some money to be able to use it as i don't have a site dedicated to an app that only i will use.

Comment: @Ian in APIs, like all things, practice makes perfect :)
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)?

There are plenty of search options (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search), and you get the response in JSON, no need for ugly HTML parsing.